# Ms Sql Split and Convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have `ID` as a varchar.  I need to split as Comma after that i need to convert list to int32.  I added example like below.

```
DECLARE @List varchar(255)

SET @List = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'

print @List
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
DECLARE @List varchar(255) = '1, 2, 23, 4, 5, 6'

DECLARE @X XML
SELECT @X  = '<myxml><nodes><n>' + 
              REPLACE(@List,',','</n></nodes><nodes><n>') + 
             '</n></nodes></myxml>'

--SELECT @X

SELECT LTRIM(C.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)')) AS item1
FROM @X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C)
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21856)**

Results:

```
| ITEM1 |
--------|--
|     1 |
|     2 |
|    23 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
```

Note: if you have spaces between numbers as per your sample data (`2 3`), you can use `Replace()` function to remove them before converting to an INT. [IsNumeric()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function may also be useful (Please read the note section of isnumeric() function for more details).

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted a script from [p.s.w.g's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string/17690735#17690735) which split a string into a in memory table of int :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitToIntList] 
    ( @string nvarchar(4000)
    , @delim nvarchar(100) )
RETURNS
    @result TABLE ([Value] int NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str nvarchar(4000)
          , @pos int 
          , @prv int = 1

    SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string)
    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @str = SUBSTRING(@string, @prv, @pos - @prv)
        INSERT INTO @result SELECT CAST(@str AS INT)

        SELECT @prv = @pos + LEN(@delim)
             , @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string, @pos + 1)
    END

    INSERT INTO @result SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@string, @prv, 4000) AS INT)
    RETURN
END
```

HTH